# Поиск и фильтрация

Tags: java

Есть задача: найти заголовки, в которых есть определённые массивом слова, и отсеять из них заголовки со словами из второго массива.

**mName** - заголовок в котором ищем слова из массива **search**. Во втором вложенном цикле  в 2-х **if**-ах, которые я почему-то решил разложить на 2 чтобы не запутаться, но всё равно запутался :( Лежит логика с проверкой по второму массиву **nosearch**
*старое*

```
for (int i = 0; i <= search.length - 1; i++) {
    if (mName.indexOf(search[i]) != -1) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= nosearch.length - 1; i1++) {
            boolean trigger = false;
            //  System.out.println(i1);
            if (mName.indexOf(nosearch[i1]) != -1) {
                trigger = false;
                System.out.println(mName);
                //  break;
            } else {
                trigger = true;
            }
            if (trigger) {
                // 
                listVakansy.add(mName);
                System.out.println(mName);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Проблема следующая: по массиву **nosearch** находится только первый попавший заголовок, все остальные безпрепятственно пропускаются в выхлоп.

*Добавил*
    Накидал отдельно и всёравно не разберусь

```
public class TestStringSearch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] search = {"тестер", "java", "системный", "cистемный", "тестировани", "тестировщик", "программист"};
    String[] nosearch = {"инженер", "микроконтроллер", "микроконтроллёр", "1c", "1С", "1c", "c#", "с#"};
    String[] str = {"ведущий java  программист", "1c программист", "инженер программист 1с", "специалист по сопровождению и тестированию", "тестировщик", "интежер", "глюк"};

    //перечисление слов
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
        //перечисление искомых слов (search)
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= search.length - 1; i1++) {
            //перечисление найденных слов
            if (str[i].indexOf(search[i1]) != -1) {
                //перечисление отрицаемых слов (nosearch)
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= nosearch.length - 1; i2++) {
                    // если находим то прерываем
                    if (str[i].indexOf(nosearch[i2]) != -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(str[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: С 2я мфами явно перестарался.....

Comment: пару раз перечитываю задачу и не догоняю.... скажи что есть и что должно получится в конце, на каком-то примере... и лучше вообще задачу можно решить элегантнее средствами джавы... без этой кучи переборов...

Comment: нужно список **str** просканировать выбрав те которые содержат слова из списка **search**, а из них убрать слова содержащие слова из списка **nosearch**   
т.е. на выхлопе должна быть отфильтрованная **str** по спискам **search** и **nosearch**  

я всё пытаюсь это сделать за "один проход"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то вы перемудрили с брейками, вот так работает:

```
public class Titles {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // titles
        final String[] titles = { "ведущий java программист", "1c программист",
                "инженер программист 1с",
                "специалист по сопровождению и тестированию", "тестировщик",
                "программист микроконтроллеров", "интежер", "глюк" };

        // include list
        final String[] includes = { "тестер", "java", "системный", "cистемный",
                "тестировани", "тестировщик", "программист" };

        // exclude list
        final String[] excludes = { "инженер", "микроконтроллер",
                "микроконтроллёр", "1c", "1С", "1c", "c#", "с#" };

        // find occurences
        final List<String> result = find(titles, includes, excludes);

        // handle result
        for (final String s : result) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    // все проверки аргументов опущены для сокращения кода
    public static List<String> find(final String[] titles,
            final String[] includes, final String[] excludes) {

        // prepare result list
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(titles.length);

        // find matches
        for (final String title : titles) {
            if (filter(title, includes) && !filter(title, excludes)) {
                result.add(title);
            }
        }

        // return result
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean filter(String title, String[] patterns) {
        for (String s : patterns) {
            if (-1 != title.indexOf(s)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
ведущий java программист
специалист по сопровождению и тестированию
тестировщик
```

Comment: гениально!  
реализация проста как дверь!  
хех, не скоро на моём уровне до таких, знаний разных тонкостей катастрофически не хватает

Comment: нету там ничего гениального. просто пытайтесь анализировать тот код который вы пишете через какое-то время после написания. вы сами будете находить в нем ошибки и куски кода которые можно переписать. а так же повторяющийся код

Answer (score 1):

```
...
if (trigger) {
                // 
                listVakansy.add(mName);
                System.out.println(mName);
                trigger = false;//break;//Думаю тут надо не break а trigger = false;
            }
        }
        //break;//А этот брейк зачем?
```

Comment: добавил полный клон алгоритма.   
где в нём допущена ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Идем по первым 2м спискам:

```
if (search[i].contains(nosearch[i]) {
```

Идем по 3му списку:

```
if (nosearch[i].contains(str[k])) {
nosearch[i].replace(str[k], "")
}
```

Попробуй разберись и допиши, что бы работало в коде... Массивы в моем коде не совпадают с твоими, но если я туплю, способ должен решить твою задачу.

Comment: нее например:  
"специалист по сопровождению и тестированию"  
по первому списку пройдёт по слову "тестировани"  

а вы сравниваете на 100% совпадение, а нужно на содержание любого слова из **search**  

далее по третьему списку (напомню команду из оригинала)  

    listVakansy.add(mName);

т.е. после прогона по первым двум for-ам, все совпадения в третьем for-e не должны вызывать данную выше команду, чем и отфильтруются

Comment: Ну так подправь индексы и циклы, что бы кажнон слово из списка, которое надр найти, проверялось в каждом элементе массива, в котором ищеш

Comment: да я уже пальцы в кровь стёр об клавиатуру, править столько, 2 дня разобраться не могу

Comment: Так че ж ты методом тыка пытаешься сделать? Неполучается, нарисуй на листке бумаги алгоритм, проверь в уме и запрограммируй